# How to solve this equation $8 \left(3^x+5^x+7^x\right)=5\cdot 2^x+2\cdot 4^x+17\cdot 6^x$?

Tags: problem-solving

I use Mathematica to solve this equation $$8 \left(3^x+5^x+7^x\right)=5\cdot
 2^x+2\cdot 4^x+17\cdot 6^x$$
and get three solutions $x=0\lor x=1\lor x=2.$ I don't know how to solve by hand. How can I solve it?

Comment: Let $f(x) = 8 \left(3^x+5^x+7^x\right) -(5\cdot 2^x+2\cdot 4^x+17\cdot 6^x)$, use caculus to draw the graph of $f(x)$ and show that $x=0, 1, 2$ are only solutions of $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Draw the graph, I think not a solve.

Comment: @John, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very low-quality question.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you're searching solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$.
Now it'easy to see that if $x$ is negative, let's say $x=-q$ with $q$ positive, the equation is not solvable as we can multiply both sides by $3^q5^q7^q$, so that the left side is an integer, but the other one clearly is not.
On the other hand if $x$ is greater than $3$, we get that the greatest power of 2 dividing the left side is always $8$, whereas the right one is divisible by $2^x$.
So you just need to check for the other cases.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: @temp, you should not answer very low-quality questions.